# Implementing Infinite scroll on a Mvx.MvxListView

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

this is in order to make an infiniteScroll with a mvxListView without touching the Android View.

i've found ItemAppearing event. my code is `local:MvxBind="ItemAppearing myCommand"` but `myCommand` never executes, somebody know why? or some body know how to hold when the scroll of a Mvx.MvxListView is at the end ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

mvvmcross Mvx.MvxlistView ItemAppearing event not exist